# Kotlin - Companion Object with Receiver Function

Tags: kotlin, receiver, companion-object

I guess it's an outright "NO", but here is my class

```
class KotlinReceiverFunction {

    val multiplyBy = fun Int.(value: Int) = this*value

    companion object {
        fun printMultiplicationResult(a: Int, b: Int) = a.multiplyBy(b) // error
    }
}
```

My question - is Receiver Function only allowed within a specific scope i.e. same as Lambdas? Or, can I get to work somehow in a companion object?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no restrictions on where a function with a receiver could be used. The problem in your case is different: `multiplyBy` is an instance member, so you need an instance of `KotlinReceiverFunction` to use it. It would be exactly the same if this function would not use a receiver:

```kotlin
val multiplyBy = fun (value1: Int, value2: Int) = value1*value2

companion object {
    fun printMultiplicationResult(a: Int, b: Int) = multiplyBy(a, b) // error
}
```

To fix the problem you need to initialize an instance of `KotlinReceiverFunction`:

```kotlin
fun printMultiplicationResult(a: Int, b: Int) =
    with(KotlinReceiverFunction()) { a.multiplyBy(b) } // works
```

Although, I think this is not exactly what you need.

Comment: So the main question is what do you try to achieve here? `multiplyBy` seems pretty static, so maybe it should be placed inside the companion as well? Maybe the whole `KotlinReceiverFunction` should be an `object` instead of a `class`? It looks like an utility holder.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with receivers. You are using the correct receiver. It's just that things declared outside the companion object is out of scope inside the companion object:

```
class KotlinReceiverFunction {
    val foo = 1
    companion object {
        fun bar() {
            println(foo) // error
        }
    }
}
```

Think of `KotlinReceiverFunction` and its companion object as two disconnected things. Under the hood on the JVM, they are just two separate classes `KotlinReceiverFunction` and `KotlinReceiverFunction$Companion`, each with their own instance members.

In the companion object, You would need an instance of `KotlinReceiverFunction` to access its `foo` property. This instance acts as the receiver.

```
companion object {
    fun bar() {
        println(KotlinReceiverFunction().foo) // OK
    }
}
```

Similarly, the `multiplyBy` function needs an instance of `KotlinReceiverFunction` as its receiver (*dispatch receiver*). But this function also needs an `Int` as a receiver (*extension receiver*)!

This makes it a little harder to access than `foo` when you are in  the companion object. You would need to provide the instance of `KotlinReceiverFunction` with a scope function, as in broot's answer.

---

If you just declare the function inside the companion object, then it will work as you expect:

```
class KotlinReceiverFunction {
    companion object {

        val multiplyBy = fun Int.(value: Int) = this*value
        fun printMultiplicationResult(a: Int, b: Int) = a.multiplyBy(b)
    }
}
```

I don't see a reason why this needs to be a `val` initialised with an anonymous function. You could have just done:

```
private fun Int.multiplyBy(value: Int) = this * value
```